# PHP reloads in stead of outputting HTML

Tags: php, get, file-get-contents

I have a PHP script that's called when submitting the order form (removed). The script does some basic verifications and uses an external API (sends a GET request with file_get_contents and stream_context_create) to register/update user info.

The problem is that sometimes it works right, but most of the times it reloads the page that called it. The page is hosted on my LAMP server (removed). If I host it locally, using the PHP build-in server, it does seem to work always.

I don't have a clue what can cause the webpage to reload instead of executing the echo statements.
The script worked right last Friday, but now it doesn't. Today I've updated PHP, but - as I expected - nothing has changed.

Obviously there isn't anything in the error_log.

Comment: with out code its impossible to help you

Comment: How would you like this community to help you?

Comment: my code is: several file_get_contents calls, $lastError = error_get_last();

Comment: do you seriously think this is answerable based on that information?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a bug with the latest FastCGI handler. With any other handler (CGI, suPHP, DSO) the script works correctly.